# Default image is not generated

Tags: 7, media

I have a `case` content-type that has an `image_field`. I have configured the field to use a default image in cases when no image is upload for a case.
I then try to render the image using the following code:

```
<?php $view = node_view($node); ?>
<div class="search-result-case">
    <div class="search-info"><?php print t('Publicerad'); ?>: <?php print date('d - M - Y', $node->created); ?></div>
    <div class="search-snippet">
    <?php print render($view['field_image']); ?>
</div>
```

If the case has a connected image then the field is rendered as expected, but in other cases nothing in displayed. When I check under recent log messages I see this:

```
Location   http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/case_170x107/public/default_images/default_case_pic_0.png?itok=CWr6R4Rs
Referrer   http://localhost/test/search/node/case
Message    Unable to generate the derived image located at public://styles/case_170x107/public/default_images/default_case_pic_0.png.
```

I don't understand why it fails to generate a style for my default image when it works fine with user supplied images.

I have checked the permission on the folder and everything seems fine, so I really don't understand why this is not working?

Notice that **all** other images that is uploaded gets their image styles generated without any problem. The error **only** gets triggered in case of a default image connected to the `field_image` field.

Comment: @ShawnConn - This isn't a duplicate. All my images gets their styles generated without any problem, except for the default image connected to the `file_image` field in the content-type.

Comment: I don't understand why people just click `close` without even reading the question? **This is not a duplicate**

Comment: I've deleted my flag comment. Hopefully, that prevents it from being re-flagged for deletion. You might want to rewrite some of the question, the "Unable..." part has a bit of a red herring effect.

Comment: Where's your default image located relative to doc root?

Comment: @tunic - It's uploaded through the field ui and stored in `public://default_images/<image.jpg>`

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth and consideration. Make sure your php.ini is configured correctly and that your. upload_max_filesize and max_file_uploads settings are adequate. My numbers are arbitrary, but I've had similar issues that require this general adjustment.

```
Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 200M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 200
```